# Как вставить картинку или другой PDF-файл в TeX/XeTeX?

Tags: pdf, tex

Как вставить в свой документ другой *PDF*-документ или картинку?
Используется *TeX*/*XeTeX* без каких-либо сторонних модулей.
**Не** *LaTeX*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользоваться командами *XeTeX* `\XeTeXpdffile`
и `\XeTeXpicfile`.
Синтаксис:

```
\XeTeXpdffile <filename> [ page <int> ] [ crop | media | bleed | trim |
  art ] [ scaled <int> | xscaled <int> | yscaled <int> | width <dimen> |
  height <dimen> | rotated <decimal> ]

\XeTeXpicfile <filename> [ scaled <int> | xscaled <int> |
  yscaled <int> | width <dimen> | height <dimen> | rotated <decimal> ]
```

Пример:

```tex
\XeTeXpdffile other_document.pdf
\XeTeXpicfile figure_1.png
```

Подробнее:
[документация по *XeTeX*](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xetexref)
(см. главу 6).